# Selenium Webdriver- Unable to search with css or xpath but search is fine with 'by id' or 'by class'

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm using Eclipse Mars and JDK 1.8. I've written the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver d1=new ChromeDriver();
WebElement e1; 
d1.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

now the following line executes perfectly:

```
e1=d1.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
```

But if I make the search with css or xpath like following, nothing yields.

```
e1=d1.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='gsfi'][name='q'][id='lst-ib']"));
```

or

```
e1=d1.findElement(By.xpath("input[@class='gsfi'][@name='q'][@id='lst-ib']"));
```

Comment: Please, can you ckeck if your selenium and chromedriver are all updated?

Comment: The CSS selector seems should work. The XPath one lacks `//` at the beginning (`//input[@class='gsfi'][....`)

Comment: I'm using Selenium 2.53 and Chrome driver 2,21.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for xpath :

```
 d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]"))
```

use this for css selector :

```
d1.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#lst-ib.gsfi"))
```

Comment: Yes it works  :)  But I can't explain why my original code didn't work. I used those type of selectors when I worked in earlier version(Kepler and Java 7).

Comment: You may use the firebug to check the css path or xpath . I verified the paths using Selenium IDE too.